# How to properly display editor instance in Joomla 4

Tags: editor, joomla-4.x

I'm currently updating my component to work in Joomla 4, and I've run into an issue with editors. I previously used this:

```
$editor = JFactory::getEditor();
$editor->display('text', $this->item->text, '', '', '', '', false);
```

I've since updated to this based one what little I could find:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Editor\Editor;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$user = Factory::getUser();
$editor = Editor::getInstance($user->getParam('editor', Factory::getConfig()->get('editor')));
$editor->display('text', $this->item->text, '', '', '', '', false);
```

I'm fully unaware of what I'm doing wrong, but the end result is I have the desired editor with a second editor nested inside.
[image: nested editors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidentally stumbled upon the answer. I hadn't realized that a parent div used the same `id="text"`, and I guess that the script for loading the editor just grabbed the first id it saw that matched.